# unsubscribe page in SFMC localized in different languages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, unsubscribe

I have a New CloudPage created and hosted for Unsubscribe Action working fine in SFMC.
Which is in English and it’s working fine.
https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/bp23vb4qfcv

but now I wanted to develop this to work for different country as per their different language like French, German, Danish etc
but the same unsub link should work for https://pub.s7.exacttarget.com/bp23vb4qfcv   all these different languages because I have already used this link in all emails.

How can I achieve this ?
Changing the same English unsubscribe cloudpage content to work for different countries localized in their different languages inside Salesforce marketing cloud ?

Comment: You can follow this blog - https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/marketing-cloud-dynamic-email-based-on-different-languages for handling dynamic languages. You may need to pass some unique ID's and fetch the language and use it in the cloud Page depending upon your needs.

Comment: @NaveenVM  thanks for the Response, yes i did handled this for Emails dynamically using Ampscript but the same doesn't work for Cloud page so looking for a solution here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a good question. However, what you are asking is a complete solution design, without telling us anything about your own attempt to solve this, which often will result in your question being closed without any answers being provided.

My recommendation would be to replace all the hardcoded texts in the cloud page with ampscript. E.g. *"I receive too many emails"* would be replaced with `%%=(@toomany)=%%`. The actual texts should be placed in a localisation data extension, with all the localised text strings in columns corresponding to the fields you want to replace, and locale as a primary key.

Once someone arrives on the cloud page, you fetch their country/locale from their profile, and find the appropriate version of the string:

```ampscript
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @locale

set @locale = AttributeValue("locale") 
set @rows = LookupRows("UnsubTranslations","locale", @locale)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)
if @rowCount > 0 then
    var @toomany
    set @row = row(@rows, 1)
    set @toomany = field(@row,"toomany")
    ]%%

<div class="sc-formfield-input">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Selection" data-field-type="Text" value="I receive too many emails">
%%=v(@toomany)=%%
</label>
</div>

%%[ else ]%%
Locale not found
%%[ endif ]%%
```

Give you lookup @locale = "da_DK", you will end up with:

```html
<div class="sc-formfield-input">
<label>
<input type="radio" name="Selection" data-field-type="Text" value="I receive too many emails">
Jeg modtager for mange emails
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example will definitely give a try on this . thanks for your time and real time example which helps a lot